# Ex 3.3.5 from Tao analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$ be functions.
Given that their composition $g\circ f :X \to Z$ is injective prove that $f$ must be injective while $g$ need not to be.
How do I proof that $g$ need not to be injective?
Without giving a counter example.
Is there a constructive proof?

Comment: Find an example

Comment: Usually the composition you intend here would be denoted as $g\circ f$.

Comment: Thanks I corrected it.

Comment: @marwalix Counterexamples not allowed.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Avoiding counterexamples seems very artificial.  But:  you could jsut remark that $g$ need only be injective on the image of $f$, and of course $f(X)$ need not be all of $Y$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks but I'stuck on the part concerning $g$.

Comment: No I checked Tao’s book. He doesn’t say counter examples not allowed for Ex 3.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \circ f$ be injective.

If $f$ weren't injective, then there would be $a,b \in X$ such that $f(a) = f(b)$, implying $(g \circ f)(a) = (g \circ f)(b)$, which is a contradiction. So $f$ must be injective.

Now suppose $f(X)$ is a proper subset of $Y$, meaning that there exists $c \in Y$ such that $c \notin f(X)$, i.e. there is no element of $X$ that is mapped to $c$ by $f$. Then pick $d := f(a)$ and suppose $g(c) = g(d)$. The map $g$ is clearly not injective, but this does not contradict the injectivity of $g \circ f$.

An example of this phenomenon is:
$$
\begin{split}
f : [0,1] \to [0,2] &\qquad f(x) := \sqrt{x}, \\
g : [0,2] \to [0,1] &\qquad g(x) := [x],
\end{split}
$$
where $[x] := x - \lfloor x \rfloor $ indicates the [decimal part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$.

Comment: Thanks.Is it a must that $g$ is injective on the image of $f : f(X)$.

Comment: Yes. Can you see why?

Comment: I can prove it but I can't see the intuition behind it .